# Kubernetes Ingress path priority (ingress-nginx)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I deployed 2 front-end applications that are based on angular. I use ingress-nginx (`k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.44.0`) with the following configurations to route the requests to these applications:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portal-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 80
```

When I hit the `<ip-address>/` it is routing to app1, but when I hit `<ip-address>/app2` it is routing back to app1.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [ingress-nginx documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#path-priority), the first step it follows is to order the paths in descending length, then it transforms these paths into nginx [location blocks](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). nginx follows a first-match policy on these blocks.

In your case, you can provide both paths, and as `/app2` is longer than `/`, it will be written first in the nginx configuration. Meaning `/app2` will have a chance to be matched first (and send the traffic to *app2*), while everything else will go to *app1*. You don't need regexes to achieve this.

Code:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portal-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 80
```